# Html Agility Pack for python

Tags: python

Is there any module for python similar to [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)?
If not, can anyone recommend me an alternative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Beautiful Soup is even better than HTML agility pack, see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818762/html-scraper-to-remove-and-modify-html-pages/1838627#1838627

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: +1 for Beautiful Soup - 'tis an excellent html processing library