# Parse text in HTML document using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have something like this `<td width='370' style='border-left: 1px solid #fff;'>text I need to get</td>` and I need to get text using Python.

How should I do it? I'm quite new to such things.

Comment: you are using Django Framwork?

Comment: related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838637/html-agility-pack-for-python

Answer (score 2):

I personally love [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in html parser module...

http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

But I'd recommend [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (Don't let the prehistoric looking homepage fool you, it's a very nice library.)

Alternatively you could try [lxml](http://lxml.de/) which is also very nice.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using Python xml Parser

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
>>> parseString(foo).getElementsByTagName("td")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
u'text I need to get'
```

A solution using BeautifulSOup

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(foo).getText()
u'text I need to get'
```

A solution using HTMPParser

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print data          
>>> MyHTMLParser().feed(foo)
text I need to get
```

A solution using Regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("<.*?>(.*)<.*?>",foo)[0]
'text I need to get'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't need all the text, just what follows that specific piece of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 >>> html='''<td width='370' style='border-left: 1px solid #fff;'>text I need to get</td>'''
 >>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
 >>> ''.join(BeautifulSoup(html).findAll(text=True))
 u'text I need to get'
 >>>
```

This solutions using BeautifulSoup,

If not installed BeautifulSoup on your system. You can install like this `sudo pip install BeautifulSoup`

Comment: I only need the text after that specific HTML, not all the text.