# Selenium for Python: How to dump current page's HTML

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using the `selenium` module, how do I dump the current page's HTML (for debugging purposes)? It doesn't say how to here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356440/need-to-dump-entire-dom-tree-with-element-id-from-selenium-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump the current page's HTML content using the `WebDriver` property `page_source`.

Sample snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://yourfavoriteurl')
if 'interested_string' in driver.page_source:
    print('String matched!')
```

Answer (score 3):

For debugging purpose to dump the current page's HTML you can invoke the `page_source` method as :

```
driver.page_source
```