# Get DOM of html in java

Tags: java, selenium, dom, webdriver, headless

I'm working with headless chrome as a Webdriver for selenium tests in JAVA.
I suspect that the DOM changes when i work with the headless version of chrome.
Is there any way to get a copy of the DOM of html during the test?

Comment: what is the usecase ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium for Python: How to dump current page's HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618287/selenium-for-python-how-to-dump-current-pages-html)

Comment: I locate elements in my test by Xpath, when i work with headless chrome the elements are found in the DOM but when i give an xpath of 3 elements for example [Editor]//[Panel]//[Button] it doesn't work. Which means the order of the elements in the DOM changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
driver.getPageSource()
```

I had a similar problem with PhantomJS and this revealed that the DOM is in fact different than on a regular browser.