# Switch pageLoadStrategy from eager to normal for existing driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

I set the `pageLoadStrategy` as `eager` but now the method I wrote to close popups of the website is not working(it works when `pageLoadStrategy` is `normal`). So **I want to know how to change the `pageLoadStrategy` from `eager` to `normal`, close the popups, and then change it back to `eager`**  I want to use `eager` as I want my code to work for low speed connections also.

here is the content of the page taken by driver.page_source when `pageLoadStrategy` is set to `eager`:

```
 <head>
  <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>
   Amizone
  </title>
  <meta content="overview &amp; stats" name="description"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
  <!-- bootstrap & fontawesome -->
  <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/color.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- page specific plugin styles -->
  <!-- text fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!-- ace styles -->
  <link href="/Content/ace.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/Dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/assets/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- end css for this page-->
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.2.1.1.min.js">
  </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

this is some of the content of the page(which I want) at the same point when `pageLoadStrategy` is set to `normal`:

````
 <head>
  <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>
   Amizone
  </title>
  <meta content="overview &amp; stats" name="description"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
  <!-- bootstrap & fontawesome -->
  <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/color.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- page specific plugin styles -->
  <!-- text fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!-- ace styles -->
  <link href="/Content/ace.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/Dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/assets/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- end css for this page-->
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.2.1.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/Scripts/ace-extra.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/Scripts/bootbox.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- page calender plugin scripts -->
  <!--start  ace scripts -->
  <script src="/Scripts/ace-elements.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/Scripts/ace.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.easypiechart.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/assets/animate-plus.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/assets/owl.carousel.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/Scripts/form-wizard.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/Scripts/validator.js">
  </script>
  <link href="/Content/color.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.colorbox.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="/Content/colorbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- include the style -->
  <link href="/Content/alertifyjs/alertify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- include a theme -->
  <link href="/Content/alertifyjs/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="/Scripts/alertify.js">
  </script>
  <link href="/Content/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <style>
   #myDiv {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
        }
  </style>
  <script>
   alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
  </script>
  <script>
   var baseurl = "";
  </script>
  <script>
   var myVar;
        function myFunction() {
            $("#lodingDiv").css("display", "block");
            myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 300);
        }
        function showPage() {
            $("#lodingDiv").css("display", "none");
            $("#myDiv").css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#myDiv").css("opacity", "1");
        }
  </script>
  <script charset="UTF-8" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/46.1/loader.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link href="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/46.1/css/core/tooltip.css" id="load-css-0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/46.1/css/util/util.css" id="load-css-1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="UTF-8" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/46.1/js/jsapi_compiled_format_module.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script charset="UTF-8" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/46.1/js/jsapi_compiled_default_module.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script charset="UTF-8" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/46.1/js/jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script charset="UTF-8" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/46.1/js/jsapi_compiled_corechart_module.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body class="no-skin modal-open" oncontextmenu="return false;" onload="myFunction()" style="padding-right: 15px;">
  <div id="lodingDiv" style="display: block;">
   <div id="loader">
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
   function beginReadNotificationNav(stype, iNoticeId) {
        var hfvalue = $('#Hf' + stype + '_' + iNoticeId).val();
        var count = $('#PendHome' + stype + 's').text();
        var actualCount = parseInt($.trim(count));
        if (hfvalue == "False" && actualCount > 0) {
            $('#PendHome' + stype + 's').text(actualCount - 1);
            $('#PendHome1' + stype + 's').text(actualCount - 1);
            $('#Pend' + stype + 's').text(actualCount - 1);
            $('#Hf' + stype + '_' + iNoticeId).val('True');
        }
    }
  </script>
  <script>
   function imageExists(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
    img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
    img.src = url;
  }


  function validateImageURL()
    {

      var imageUrl = 'https://amizone.net/amizone/Images/Signatures/7071804_P.png';

      imageExists(imageUrl, function(exists) {
          //Show the result
         // alert('Fileexists=' + exists);
          var html='';  
                if (exists)
          {
                    html= '<img class="nav-user-photo" src="https://amizone.net/amizone/Images/Signatures/7071804_P.png"/>';
             }
              else
              {
                    html = '<img class="nav-user-photo" src="../Images/blankphoto.png"  />';
              }
         // alert(html);
          $('#userphoto').append(html);

      });

  }

    validateImageURL();
  </script>
  <style>
   .margin-left-20{margin-left:20px}
    .top-notice li {
        line-height: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .Nav-Note-Title {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #0eb2a4;
    }

    .Nav-Note-Date {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #18960a;
    }

    .Nav-Note-View a {
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 2px 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    @media(min-width:767px) {

        .modal-close-btn-home {
        display:none;
        }
    }
  </style>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default ace-save-state navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    try { ace.settings.check('navbar', 'fixed') } catch (e) { }
   </script>
   <div class="navbar-container" id="navbar-container">
    <button class="navbar-toggle menu-toggler pull-left" data-target="#sidebar" id="menu-toggler" type="button">
     <span class="sr-only">
      Toggle sidebar
     </span>
     <span class="icon-bar">
     </span>
     <span class="icon-bar">
     </span>
     <span class="icon-bar">
     </span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home/">
      <img src="/images/amizone-logo-inner.png"/>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left">
     <h4 class="align-middle white margin-left-20">
      Amity University Uttar Pradesh, Noida
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-buttons pull-right" role="navigation">
     <ul class="nav ace-nav">
      <li class="grey dropdown-modal">
       <a aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-bell">
        </i>
        <span class="badge badge-grey" id="PendHomeNotifications">
         10
        </span>
       </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu-right dropdown-navbar dropdown-menu dropdown-caret dropdown-close">
        <li class="dropdown-header">
         <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check">
         </i>
         <span id="PendHome1Notifications">
          10
         </span>
         Notices To Read
         <button aria-label="Close" class="close modal-close-btn-home" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">
           ×
          </span>
         </button>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-content ace-scroll" style="position: relative;">
         <div class="scroll-track" style="display: none;">
          <div class="scroll-bar">
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-content" style="max-height: 200px;">
          <div class="scroll-content" style="">
           <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-navbar top-notice">
            <li>
             <input id="HfNotification_6699" type="hidden" value="False"/>
             <span class="Nav-Note-Title">
              NOTICE FOR ALL -- LOST &amp; FOUND
             </span>
             <div class="clearfix">
              <span class="pull-left Nav-Note-Date">
               13 Jan 2020
              </span>
              <span class="pull-right Nav-Note-View">
               <a class="bg-b-blue" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="beginReadNotificationNav('Notification','6699');" data-ajax-loading="#lodingDiv" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success=" $('#FormModal').modal('show');" data-ajax-update="#DivForm" href="/Home/NoticeDescription/6787102C-D0F6-4AF2-8E58-4D6F9FF3D4C8?Type=2" id="6787102C-D0F6-4AF2-8E58-4D6F9FF3D4C8" rel="0">
                View
               </a>
              </span>
             </div>
            </li>
            <li>
             <input id="HfNotification_6700" type="hidden" value="False"/>
             <span class="Nav-Note-Title">
              COMPLETE BAN ON E-CIGARETTES
             </span>
             <div class="clearfix">
              <span class="pull-left Nav-Note-Date">
               10 Jan 2020
              </span>
              <span class="pull-right Nav-Note-View">
               <a class="bg-b-blue" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="beginReadNotificationNav('Notification','6700');" data-ajax-loading="#lodingDiv" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success=" $('#FormModal').modal('show');" data-ajax-update="#DivForm" href="/Home/NoticeDescription/F81A5BB8-68BE-4B92-8DD0-2A76F1880197?Type=2" id="F81A5BB8-68BE-4B92-8DD0-2A76F1880197" rel="0">
                View
               </a>
              </span>
             </div>
            </li>
            <li>```

this is the python automation code:
````

````
#import sys
import time
import db
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

start_time = time.time()    #stores time at which program starts
#while(True):

#***setting up chrome driver***
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #complete
#caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #interactive
#caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
chromedriver = "/usr/share/chromedriver/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps,executable_path=chromedriver)
driver.set_window_size(800, 1000)
# driver.set_network_conditions(
#     offline=False,
#     latency=5,  # additional latency (ms)
#     download_throughput=500 * 1024,  # maximal throughput
#     upload_throughput=500 * 1024)  # maximal throughput
#driver.maximize_window()
#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait = driver.implicitly_wait(10)
url = "https://student.amizone.net"
driver.get(url) #getting amizone.net

#***write page content to a file and return page soup***
def page_content_to_file(*argsv):
    wait
    content = driver.page_source
    #print(content)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    page_soup_text = BeautifulSoup.prettify(page_soup)
    if(len(argsv) > 1):
        raise NameError('page_content_to_file cannot take more than 2 arguments')
    if(len(argsv) == 1):
        filename = argsv[0]
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
            file.write(page_soup_text)
            print("wrote to file {}".format(filename))
    return page_soup

#***function that enters login credentials***
def login(username, password):
    try:
    #type | name=_UserName
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "_UserName").send_keys(username)
    #type | name=_Password
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "_Password").send_keys(password)
    #click | css=#loginform .login100-form-btn |  
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#loginform .login100-form-btn").click()
    except:
        print("couldn't complete login")

#***function to close popups***
def close_popups():
    #try:
    page_soup = page_content_to_file("popup.html")
    #   getting names of divs having class 'modal fade in'
        # driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        # content = driver.page_source
        # page_soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
    popup_divs = page_soup.find_all('div', {"class":"modal fade in"})
#print(popup_divs)
    popups_name = []
    for div in popup_divs:
        popups_name.append(div['id'])
        print(popups_name)
    if(len(popups_name) == 0):
        print("no popups found popups_name length=0")
    else:
        print("starting")
    #   clicking to close pop-ups
        for name in reversed(popups_name):
            xpath = "//div[@id='" + name + "']//button[@class='close']"
            print(xpath)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click()
        print("clicks complete")
            #extra code
                #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ModalPopAmityHostel button.btn"))).click()
                #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#StudentSatisfactionPop button.btn"))
                #click | id=ModalPopAmityHostel |  
                #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ModalPopAmityHostel']//button[@class='close']").click()
                #click | id=StudentSatisfactionPop | 
                #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='StudentSatisfactionPop']//button[@class='close']").click()
    # except:
        # print("error occured while closing popups")
    return 0

#----------FUNCTION CALLS----------
login("username", "password") #login
close_popups() #close all popups
#----------------------------------

#***go to next/prev date in myClasses***
page_soup = page_content_to_file("amizone.html")
date_prev_next = ""
while(date_prev_next != "end"):
    date_prev_next = input("type prev/next:")
    try:
        if(date_prev_next == "next"):
            #click | css=.fc-icon-right-single-arrow |
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fc-icon-right-single-arrow").click()
            print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='calendar']/div[1]/div[3]/h2").text)
        if(date_prev_next == "prev"):
            # click | css=.fc-prev-button |
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fc-prev-button").click()
            print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='calendar']/div[1]/div[3]/h2").text)
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException as e:
        print(e, "unable to click. Something may be blocking the element")

#***clicking on the hamburger button and choosing timetable***
def menu_click(option):
    menu_toggler_xpath = "//*[@id='menu-toggler']" #xpath of the menu toggler(hamburger button)
    #   clicking on the hamburger button on top left corner
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, menu_toggler_xpath).click()
    if(option == "timetable"):
        time_table_navbar_xpath = "//*[@id='10']" #xpath of the timetable option in menu
        #   clicking on the timetable button in the menu
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, time_table_navbar_xpath).click()
        print("clicked on timetable.")
        wait

menu_click("timetable")
#***scraping timetable***
# print(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "tab-content").text)
#NOTE: no need to click on weekdays because all info is in the webpage
#NOTE: just clicking on the tt loads only the current day's tt. if then you click once on any day webpage shows tt of whole week.(why?)
#for i in range(1,8): #iterating over all weekdays 1-7
    #weekday_xpath = "//*[@id='myTab3']/li[" + str(i) + "]/a" #concatenating string to make xpath for each weekday
#clicking on a day to get whole week's tt
page_soup = page_content_to_file("01.html")
weekday_xpath = "//*[@id='myTab3']/li[1]/a" #xpath of day no.1 of the week in the timetable at that time.
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, weekday_xpath).click()

#   get info about classes and attendance marked from myclasses
#TODO: for a course check whether green or blue dot is shown

#extra code
    #date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='calendar']/div[1]/div[3]/h2").text #to get the date of myClasses
    #print(calendar_date_element.text)
    #driver.find_element(By.ID, "ModalPopAmityHostel").click()
    #time.sleep(5)
    #driver.implicitly_wait(5000)
    #driver.find_element(By.ID, "StudentSatisfactionPop").click()
    #url = driver.current_url
    #driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "close").click()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(5000)
period_data = [] #list to make sql statement
#scraping timetable data
page_soup = page_content_to_file()
divs_class_tab_pane = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"tab-pane"})  #finds and makes a list all the <div class="tab-pane in active" id="[day]">
for day_div in divs_class_tab_pane:    #selects each day's div from divs_class_tab_pane list
    print()
    day = day_div["id"].strip()    #gets the id attribute of div tag e.g <div class="tab-pane in active" id="Sunday"> returns the day
    print(day)
    try:
        #find all <div class="thumbnail timetable-box"> elements which contains p tags of details of a class
        div_thumbnail_timetable_box = day_div.findAll("div", {"class":"thumbnail timetable-box"})
        if(len(div_thumbnail_timetable_box) == 0):
            print("no classes alloted yet")
    except:
        print("no classes today")
    #selecting element one at a time from div_thumbnail_timetable_box
    for ttbox in div_thumbnail_timetable_box:   
        period_data.append(day) #appending day to list
        print()
        #get text from <p class="class-time"> the class time
        class_time = ttbox.find('p', {"class":"class-time"}).text.strip()
        period_data.append(class_time) #appending class time to list
        print(class_time)
        #get text from <p class="course-code"> the course code
        course_code = ttbox.find('p', {"class":"course-code"}).text.strip()
        period_data.append(course_code) #appending course_code to list
        print(course_code)
        #get text from <p class="course-teacher"> the course teacher
        course_teacher = ttbox.find('p', {"class":"course-teacher"}).text.strip()
        period_data.append(course_teacher) #appending course_teacher to list
        print(course_teacher)
        class_location = ttbox.find('p', {"class":"class-loc"}).text.strip()
        period_data.append(class_location)
        print(class_location)
        print(period_data)

        #connecting to database #TODO: exception handliling required here
        mydb = db.establish_con("localhost", "manik", "sweetbread","amizone")
        script = "','".join(period_data)
        period_data.clear()
        query = "INSERT INTO amizone.tt_data(`day`,`time`,course,teacher, class_loc) VALUES ('" + script + "');"
        #running MySQL query in the database
        mycursor = db.run_sql(mydb, query)
        #mycursor = db.run_sql(mydb, "SELECT * FROM amizone.tt_data;")
        mydb.commit()
#driver.quit()
print("execution time: %ss" % (round(time.time() - start_time, 5)))
#    time.sleep(10)```
````

Comment: PageLoadSetting is an attribute on the particular driver instance you are testing with, and I don't think there is a way to change the strategy without creating a new driver object thus restarting the session.

Comment: @Christine what do you suggest I should do then? I don't want to wait for the whole site to load(only in case of popups because they are not closing in eager strategy). I want it to work for low speed connections as it takes too much time to load images.

Comment: You could leave page load strategy as `eager`, and use `WebDriverWait`on the pop ups you are trying to close. When you say closing the popups is "not working", what error message is showing and which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: there is an expectedCondition of numberofWindowsToBe:  https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe-int-

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider a couple of things as follows:

- As you set the [pageLoadStrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628) as **`eager`** through `DesiredCapabilities()` this configuration gets baked into the *chromedriver* executable and will persist till the lifetime of the *WebDriver* instance. So, you can't change the [pageLoadStrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver/43737358#43737358) either from `eager` to `normal` or vice versa while the test execution is *In Progress*.
- You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

  - [Set capability on already running selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224348/set-capability-on-already-running-selenium-webdriver/46232538#46232538)
  - [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023853/change-chromeoptions-in-an-existing-webdriver/53025100#53025100)
- Comparing the [Page Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618287/selenium-for-python-how-to-dump-current-pages-html/49621170#49621170) obtained by the *WebDriver* variant using both the [pageLoadStrategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087832/eager-page-load-strategy-workaround-for-chromedriver-selenium-in-python/51097396#51097396) you will observe:

  - The *Page Source* with `pageLoadStrategy` as *eager* doesn't contains the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) cals:

    ```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.2.1.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js">
    </script>
    ```
  - Hence, there are higher possibilities that the *WebDriver* variant will attemptan interaction e.g. `click()`, `send_keys()` even before the [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) registers different [HTML DOM Events](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) e.g. event handlers, on elements with in the HTML document which eventually will result in `click()` **failures**.

This is the exact reason behind the *...popup not getting closed...*.

---

### Solution

From the *Page Source* with `pageLoadStrategy` as *eager*, it is quite evident the elements on the webpage are *JavaScript* enabled elements, so a better approach would be to use `pageLoadStrategy` as **`normal`** through the test execution.